# How to make a realistic spotlight with defocus effects

Tags: node-editor, image

I'm trying to use spotlight to project image on a plane, and hope to get blurred images with different defocus level in different position, just like a realistic projector. But actully the projected image is always clear no matter how I change the position of the plane. My node tree of the spotlight is shown below. Is there any way to solve it?

[image: spotlight node tree]

[image: spotlight and plane]

Comment: You should check the material of the image. If it is an emission one, no matter the lighting, the image will always be visible clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the *light falloff* node to control intensity, then you need to use the *quadratic* output, not the linear output.  You also need to move the light much farther away from the projection screen to give the falloff a chance to work.  If you do this, you do not need to manipulate the XYZ coordinates and you end up with a node tree along these lines:

[image: using light fall off]

However, I prefer to have more control over the falloff, so instead of the light falloff node, I use a *spherical gradient* node and a math node.

Here is my entire node tree for such a projector.

[image: Using a gradient texture to control falloff]

The top part of the tree, in the frame labeled *Only project forward* is cosmetic and not related to the falloff.  It merely makes sure that the plane I'm using as a projector only projects in one direction.

The second part, labeled *Image to Project* is, of course, how you attach the image to the *Emission* node.  In this case, since I imported the image using the *Images as Planes* add-on, I don't really need the *Texture Coordinate* or top *mapping* nodes.

The third part is the "fun" part.

- The bottom *mapping* node is needed to center the gradient.  Without it, the sphere will be centered in the lower left corner of the lamp plane.  By mapping with a (-.5, -.5) offset, I've moved the center of the sphere to the center of the image.  So the gradient looks like this:

[image: gradient]

- The *gradient* node does the math to give the falloff.  As you can see, the corners are darker than the edges.
- The *math* node controls how intense the light is.  Multiplying by a number smaller than 1 gives a greater falloff.  The smaller the number, the more pronounced the effect.

That's a multiply node, but I sometimes use a multiply/add node.  The multiply controls the effect while the add sets the basic intensity of the light.

Here's an example setup.  The smaller plane is the "spotlight". The larger plane is the projection screen.

[image: basic setup with spot and screen]

Even so, the effect is very subtle unless you move the spotlight farther from the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very close to the effect I want. Can I focus on a object or adjust focus distance through this way?

Comment: Other than changing the math node to a color ramp and hand tuning the color ramp to get the falloff pattern you want, I don't know of a way. It could probably be done with geometry nodes in 2.93, but I don't know enough to say how.